# SynfolderItems behaving erratically

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am using Exchange_2010_SP3 .

When I use this code : connect as exchange2010_SP1, oldest items are returned . This is what I expected

```
exchangeService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1,
                                        TimeZoneInfo.Utc);

var items = exchangeService.SyncFolderItems(_folderId, PropertySet.IdOnly, null,
                                            Configuration.BatchSize,
                                            SyncFolderItemsScope.NormalItems,
                                            null);
```

But when I initialize exchangeService as SP2 , latest items are returned. (This has taken me by total surprise).

```
exchangeService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2,
                                      TimeZoneInfo.Utc);

var items = exchangeService.SyncFolderItems(_folderId, PropertySet.IdOnly, null,
                                            Configuration.BatchSize,
                                            SyncFolderItemsScope.NormalItems,
                                            null);
```

Trying to figure out, how SyncFolderItems behaves when using different version of exchange in code than that you are trying to connect to. Tried to find documentation related to this but without success.

Any pointers, help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're exactly right, in Exchange 2010 SP2, the order changed.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440952(v=exchg.150).aspx: In Exchange Online, Exchange Online as part of Office 365, and versions of Exchange starting with Exchange 2010 SP2, items and folders are returned in order from newest to oldest. In previous versions of Exchange, items and folders are returned from oldest to newest.

Comment: @ Mimi, Thanks for the swift response!!!. I was wondering how synchronization works for new emails  when you are getting emails from latest to oldest. Any Idea??

Comment: SyncFolderItems doesn't work on dates and times to get new data, it uses the syncState parameter to determine what changes the client already knows about. So if your mailbox has already been synchronized, and then you get a new message, and then you call SyncFolderItems, the syncState parameter you include in the SyncFolderItems call lets the server know that the client already had all the other content/changes in the mailbox, and the only change since the last sync is the one new message. Make sense?

Comment: Yup absolutely. I figured out that my whole understanding of SyncSate was wrong. Till now i was wrongly assuming that SyncState calculation also takes date into account. Can you tell me how SyncState is exactly generated to be able to determine what need to be synced and what need not ?

Comment: I'm not sure if the EWS method calls the RPCs documented in the MS-OXCFXICS protocol document behind the scenes [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc463916(v=exchg.80).aspx), but I'll try to find out. If they share the same logic, then MS-OXCFXICS has all the answers.